# Getting possible dictionary key names?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, nsdictionary

How can I tell what options I have for `objectForKey:` calls? How do I know what values are non-null for the 'forKey' portion of the message?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`NSArray * keys = [myDictionary allKeys];`